# Sorting JSON alphabetically(with empty value at last)

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have a JSON, that is formatted like:

```
account = [
     {"name":"Los Angeles", "country":"USA"},
     {"name":"Boston", "country":"USA"},
     {"name":"", "country":"USA"},
     {"name":"Chicago", "country":"USA"}
]
```

I am trying to sort this alphabetically A-Z BY NAME with empty name values at last.

I have tried this, but, this sorts A-Z with empty values at first.

```
account.sort( function( a, b ) {
    return a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: FYI, you can make use of `localeCompare`:  `return a.city.localeCompare(b.city);`

Answer (score 8):

```
account.sort( function( a, b ) {
    if(a.name === "") {
       return 1;
    } else if(b.name === "") {
       return -1;
    } else {
         return a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0;
    }
});
```

In case of strings, empty strings are considered to be the smallest value, hence, are sorted out as the first element in array.

However, we need to change the default behavior as per our requirement so we have to add extra logic for it.

Now in sorting, when we return -1, it means the order is fine and as desired. When we return 1, it means the order is the opposite and needs to be swapped, and when returns 0, both objects/values are same and no action is required.

Now, in our case, we need to move empty strings to the last. Hence, if the first object/value is empty string, swap it and move it towards right in array. And when the second object/value is empty string, no action is required as it is required to be at last.

Hence, this is how things are working.

Comment: Care to explain your solution? That would be more valuable.

Comment: I remember your words Felix, i will do that for sure

Comment: thanks for replying @nikhil, but, it is still the same sorting result.

Comment: You have to account for both `a` and `b` being empty. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30872577/227299

Comment: @ShashiSingh - Please check now. There was a small miss in my code. I am adding details in a while.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `a.name` and `b.name`?

Comment: @nikhil its working now, please explain me the logic

Comment: @ShashiSingh - Just few mins. Adding

Comment: @ShashiSingh - I have added the explanation. Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 6):

You need extra clauses to test for empty strings.

```js
account = [{
  "name": "Los Angeles",
  "country": "USA"
}, {
  "name": "Boston",
  "country": "USA"
}, {
  "name": "",
  "country": "USA"
}, {
  "name": "Chicago",
  "country": "USA"
}]
account.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (b.name.length == 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.name.length == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return a.city.localeCompare(b.city);
});
console.log(account)
```

Comment: beuatiful. Thanks for providing a snippet

Comment: Same here: Explanation? :)

Comment: @FelixKling Added, I tend to post answers in bits to beat others :)

Answer (score 4):

No need for extra ifs.

```js
account = [
     {"name":"Los Angeles", "country":"USA"},
     {"name":"Boston", "country":"USA"},
     {"name":"", "country":"USA"},
     {"name":"Chicago", "country":"USA"}
]

account.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a.name || "zzz").localeCompare(b.name || "zzz");
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(account,null,3))
```

`a.name || "zzz"` means "if a.name is not empty, use that, otherwise use something that is 'bigger' than any name".

Comment: As long as you don't have a city named `"zzzz"` ;)

Comment: How about a city named 豊橋市 (Toyohashi)? That will sort at the end. Just saying... this style of "something that is bigger than any name" is brittle, my solution works without relying on additional knowledge, and reads more like the requirement, making it easier to understand.

Comment: @JuanMendes: basically, the idea here is the same as `max=-Infinity` in sorting algorithms. Very common and idiomatic. Feel free to use `\uFFFF` instead of `zzz` if you deal with unicodes.

Comment: I do understand the idea, I am just pointing out that for a generic case (if you were comparing objects and wanted nulls to go to the end), this technique would not work but the "extra if" would.

Comment: This is the simplest response - I was using null as the default, racking my brains out for a solution --- the only improvement being use "\uFFFF" for ascending sorts and "\u0000" for descending sorts.